# HttpStringContent Making JSON Invalid?

Tags: json, uwp, windows-10-universal, dotnet-httpclient

```
httpClient = new HttpClient();
stringContent = new HttpStringContent(postBody, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json");
httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
String responseString = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Writing a UWP app and trying to send JSON data to a web server. In another method when I serialize an object to JSON `postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parentModel);`, I get valid JSON:

```
"{\"ParentId\":\"uwp@test.com\",\"ParentPrimaryId\":\"uwp@test.com\",\"ParentPassword\":\"n78mG2LB18ANtzr7gd2X/fILNELjbjOMuTWbhWoDvcg=\",\"ParentFirstName\":\"Bill\",\"ParentLastName\":\"Gates\",\"AddChildDistrictId\":\"\",\"RemoveChildDistrictId\":\"\",\"ParentToken\":null,\"ParentDistrictId\":\"\",\"ParentChildDistricts\":\"\",\"AppPlatform\":\"Windows 10.0.15063.138\",\"AppVersion\":10000,\"ParentAccountStatus\":1,\"ParentStatusCode\":0,\"ParentFailedSignInAttempt\":0}"
```

However, when I pass the post body to HttpStringContent, it gives me:

```
{{"ParentId":"uwp@test.com","ParentPrimaryId":"uwp@test.com","ParentPassword":"n78mG2LB18ANtzr7gd2X/fILNELjbjOMuTWbhWoDvcg=","ParentFirstName":"Bill","ParentLastName":"Gates","AddChildDistrictId":"","RemoveChildDistrictId":"","ParentToken":null,"ParentDistrictId":"","ParentChildDistricts":"","AppPlatform":"Windows 10.0.15063.138","AppVersion":10000,"ParentAccountStatus":1,"ParentStatusCode":0,"ParentFailedSignInAttempt":0}}
```

Which is invalid JSON. Is this what is being sent? Why does it add the extra outer brace and remove the beginning quotation marks?

Comment: When you say "it gives me", what is "it" exactly? Please explain how exactly you're getting that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect those are actually the same string at the byte level, and the difference is in how Visual Studio is displaying them to you.

The first example is a syntactically correct C# literal string, surrounded in quotes with internal quotes escaped. The *actual* string of course doesn't contain backslash characters or starting/ending quotes; those are just required to *represent* the string in C#.

The second example looks like how Visual Studio's debugging tools display an object and its contents. In this case, the outer `{}` are how VS tells you it's a object; those characters aren't in the actual string.

So again, I think they are byte-for-byte the same actual string, just represented differently by the IDE.

Comment: I suspected it was VS debugger just  displaying the string a certain way. Thanks for the confirm.